# Как сделать добавление тэгов к статье в форме как на stackoverflow в Django

Tags: python, django

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать добавление тегов в форме создания статьи на Django сайте. Вот что у меня есть сейчас:
[image: фото формы]

Для модели тегов я использую в модели Article ManyToManyField.

views.py:

```
class AddArticle(LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = AddArticleForm
    template_name = 'articles/add_article.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('articles')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title='Создание статьи')
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.username = self.request.user
        obj.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py:

```
class AddArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].empty_label = "Тэг не выбран"

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), to_field_name='tags')
        fields = ['title', 'cover_image', 'content', 'tags']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-input form__input',
                                                   'placeholder': 'Введите название статьи'}),
                   'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-input form__input',
                                                    'placeholder': 'Введите текст статьи'}),
                   'cover_image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-input form__file-btn'})}
```

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Автор')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=False, verbose_name='Обложка')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата изменения')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', verbose_name='Тэги')
    views_count = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0, verbose_name='Количество просмотров')
    comments_count = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0, verbose_name='Количество комментариев')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, auto_created=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article', kwargs={'article_slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag', kwargs={'tag_slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тэг'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тэги'
```

add_article.html:

```
{% block content %}
<section class="add-article">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10 form-container">
                <form class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="text-center form__errors">{{form.non_field_errors}}</div>

                    <div class="row">
                    {% for item in form %}
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="form__label" for="{{item.id_for_label}}">{{item.label}}: </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                {{item}}
                            </div>

                    <div class="form__errors">{{item.errors}}</div>

                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                    <button class="form__btn btn" type="submit">Опубликовать статью</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

Так вот в чём вопрос: как я могу сделать аналогичную систему добавления тегов как на stackoverflow? То есть мне нужна форма, в которой при нажатии на кнопку можно будет выбрать из списка нужный тег, а потом нажать второй раз и добавить второй и т. д.